# Convert the event data according to some config data

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I have an `array` of `JSON`, `config`  data.

```
var config =  [ [{'state': 'step1'}],
                [{'state': 'step2'}] , 
                [{'state': 'step3'}]
              ];
```

In `config`, data are in ordered form.

I also have a `JSON`, `Events` data, which has these **`state`** but they are not in sequential order. I want to convert below `Events` data based on `config`.

```
Events: [ 
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step2' },
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step3' },
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step1' } ,
           { Status: 'completed', State: 'step3'}  
       ],
```

Also, last step of config will have two entry and for that rendered state should come before completed.

Result that I am expecting is :

```
Events: [ 
            { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step1' },
            { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step2' },
            { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step3' } ,
            { Status: 'completed', State: 'step3' }  
        ]
```

PS : I don't have any working/error prone code for this as of now. Basically  I am not being able to think how to incorporate `config` for making changes in `Events`.

Thanks

Comment: `config` is invalid `'state': 'step1'` should be in `{}`

Comment: @MaheerAli changed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transform `config` into an array of strings, and then use `.sort` while comparing the difference in `indexOf` of the `States` property in that array:

```js
var config =  [ [{'state': 'step1'}],
        [{'state': 'step2'}] , 
        [{'state': 'step3'}]
      ];
const Events = [ 
   { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step2' },
   { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step3' },
   { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step1' } ,
   { Status: 'completed', State: 'step3'}  
];

const eventOrders = config.map(([{ state }]) => state);
Events.sort((a, b) => (
  eventOrders.indexOf(a.State) - eventOrders.indexOf(b.State)
  || Events.indexOf(a) - Events.indexOf(b)
));
console.log(Events);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once I evaluate your solution with different scenario. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Logic to keep `rendered` before `completed` is missing.

Comment: @We'wake yes just observed it. Can you help to do it ?

Comment: @AtulKumar Are you specifically looking for `rendered` and `completed` sorting or there can be other strings at the place of  `rendered` and `completed` ?

Comment: The code in the answer as it is currently preserves the current relative ordering in the `Events` array if their respective `State`s are the same.

Comment: Yes but @AtulKumar wants `rendered` should come before `completed`.

Comment: @AtulKumar I have updated Snow's answer, please check and confirm if it works in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks @We'wake :)

Comment: @AtulKumar I think snow didn't approve my answer, I am adding my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps

- First convert array from config like `['step1','step2','step3']`
- Use `sort()` on `events`
- Then sort the objects in `events` bases on `indexOf()` `State` property of item in the above array.

```js
var config =  [ [{'state': 'step1'}],
                [{'state': 'step2'}] , 
                [{'state': 'step3'}]
              ];

let states = config.map(x => x[0].state);
const events = [ 
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step2' },
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step3' },
           { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step1' } ,
           { Status: 'completed', State: 'step3'}  
       ]
 const res = events.sort((a,b) => states.indexOf(a.State) - states.indexOf(b.State));
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me hope it helps you.

```
function arrangeOrder(arrNeedToArrange, accToArrange, keyOfarrNeedsToArrange, keyOfArrAccToArange) {
let arrangedArr = [];
accToArrange.map((val) => {
    let res = arrNeedToArrange.filter(obj => { return obj[keyOfarrNeedsToArrange] == val[0][keyOfArrAccToArange] });
    res.map(r => arrangedArr.push(r))
})
 return arrangedArr;
}

function setAtLastToObj(arr, key, val) {
  let lastObj = {};
  arr = arr.filter((obj) => {
    if (obj[key] == val) {
        lastObj = obj;
    }
    return obj[key] != val
 });
 arr.push(lastObj);
 return arr;
}

 let arr = arrangeOrder(Events, config, 'State', 'state');
 arr = setAtLastToObj(arr, 'Status', 'completed');
```

Comment: This is not considering for last step rendered should come before completed.

Answer (score 0):

> Added the logic to keep `rendered` before `completed` if `State` are same.

```
var config =  [ 
    [{'state': 'step1'}],
    [{'state': 'step2'}], 
    [{'state': 'step3'}]
];

const Events = [ 
    { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step2' },
    { Status: 'completed',  State: 'step3' },
    { Status: 'rendered',  State: 'step1' } ,
    { Status: 'rendered', State: 'step3'}  
];

const eventOrders = config.map( ([{state}]) => state);

Events.sort((a, b) => {    
    let result = eventOrders.indexOf(a.State) - eventOrders.indexOf(b.State);
    if(result == 0){
        if(a.Status=='rendered' && b.Status=='completed') return -1;
        if(b.Status=='rendered' && a.Status=='completed') return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    return result;
});

console.log(Events);
```